# Show that the field of real numbers has an infinite proper subfield but no finite subfields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Show that the field of real numbers has an infinite proper subfield but no finite subfields.
$\mathbb{Q}$ is an infinite subfield and as $|\mathbb{Q}| < |\mathbb{R}|$, it is also a proper subfield. But how do I prove that $\mathbb{R}$ has no finite subfield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest subfield is called prime field. Since $\mathbb{R}$ has characteristic zero, the prime field cannot be finite, because then the characteristic would be a prime $p>0$. The characteristic of $K$ determines its prime field, and for $K=\mathbb{R}$ it is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

If it had a finite subfield it would have an element $z$ such that $nz=0$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k\mathbb{Q}=\{kx\; :\;  x\in \mathbb{Q}\}$. There are infinitely many irrational numbers of the form $m=\sqrt{n}$, where $n$ is positive natural number. Hence, the set $ \{ (\sqrt{n}\mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{Q},+,\cdot) \; : \; n \mbox{ is a positive integer}\} $ contains an infinite sub-fields of $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot)$. Since every natural number is a finite sum of $1$, the closure property of $+$ over the sub-field implies that no finite sub-field for $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot)$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

Define $p = \mathrm{char}(F)$, the characteristic of the field $F$, as the integer $p$ for which the map $\mathbb Z \to F$ has kernel $p \mathbb Z$ and thus gives the injection  $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z \to F$. In characteristic zero this gives the canonical inclusion $\mathbb Q \to F$, and in characteristic $p > 0$ this gives $\mathbb F_p \to F$.

This separates the world of fields of different characteristics ; in particular, if $F$ has characteristic $p$ and $K$ has characteristic $q$, then there are no field homomorphisms $F \to K$ or $K \to F$. This is because an homomorphism $\mathbb F_p \to F$ for $p > 0$ is equivalent to saying that $p \cdot 1 \overset{def}= 1+1+\cdots +1 = 0$ ($1$ added $p$ times), and if there is an homomorphism $F \to K$, then if $p \cdot 1_F = 0$, then $p \cdot 1_K = 0$ (because homomorphisms of fields carry $1$ to $1$).

In particular, a field of characteristic $0$ *must* be infinite, since it contains $\mathbb Q$ as a subfield. In other words, this has nothing to do with the real numbers.

Hope that helps,